Converting pt to tflite in Python
I am currently using Python 3.12.6, but I have noticed that there are limited TensorFlow package versions available for this newer version.
I would like to know which packages and versions are compatible with Python 3.11.6 for converting a .pt file to a .tflite file.
Additionally, I have tried using Python 3.9.12 with the following packages:
```
pip install numpy==1.23.5
pip install tensorflow==2.12.0
pip install tensorflow-intel==2.12.0
pip install tensorflow-probability==0.18.0
pip install onnx==1.13.0
pip install onnxruntime==1.14.0
pip install torch==2.0.1
pip install torchvision==0.15.2
pip install torchaudio==2.0.2
```

However, I have not been able to successfully convert the file.
Could anyone suggest the appropriate Python version, along with the necessary packages and their versions, to successfully convert .pt files to .tflite files?
Thank you!

Try this:
https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/model_export/#export-a-trained-yolov5-model
git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5
cd yolov5
python3.11 -m venv venv
source .venv/bin/activate # Linux/Mac
venv\Scripts\activate # Windows
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
python export.py --weights /path/to/your-yolov5s.pt --include torchscript tflite

